# How accurate are flex sensors?

Tags: sensor, accuracy, flex

So for the project I am working on I plan on measuring very precise changes in angle, possibly up to 5 degrees of accuracy.

- Are polymer ink sensors (the classic Nintendo power glove flex sensor) the way to go?
- Can they really be that accurate or are there any other alternatives to measure bend on an attached apparatus pricisely?

Comment: The best way to know is to read the specs of the specific sensor.

Comment: they are "accurate", but to what standard? Sounds like it's more a problem of precision. Can you use a magnet and hall-effect sensor instead? those don't wear-out...

Comment: what are you measuring the angle of?

Answer (score 1):

I think if the geometry is such that you can make the sensor flex exactly the same way for each motion, you can get 5 degree performance.  If the goemetry moves around, you might not.  You're likely somewhere in between these two cases.  Sounds like a quick test is in order to determine if the method is worth putting more effort into.

Answer (score 0):

They can be as accurate as measuring 5 degrees (depending on the configuration) but as long as you are willing to calibrate it, that is often the difficult bit. Make sure you set it up in such a way that you can replicate it and do your own tests. You may even be able to get it better than the requirements.